# JavaScript + Canvas Moving Object

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a pong-game in Canvas. I figured I would start by making the ball move across the street. The problem is when I loop the draw-function it turns into a line, instead of a ball at each new position. (See screenshot below.)

[image]

I thought clearing the canvas and then re-drawing everything would solve the problem, but apparently not.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="sv">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Super Pong!</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="superPong.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul id="navlist">
                <li><a href="#">Button 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Button 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Button 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Button 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="content">
            <canvas width="1000" height="600">Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas</canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #E93D19;
    color: #341711;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2vw;
}

#content {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 3%;
}

canvas {
    background-color: white;
}

nav {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3vw;
}

#navlist {
    background-color: #FD851D;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    transform: translateY(10%);
}

#navlist li {
    display: inline;
}

#navlist a {
    color: #C91D09;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navlist a:hover {
    background-color: #C91D09;
    color: #FD851D;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded, false);

function eventWindowLoaded(){
    var canvas=document.querySelector("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canWidth=canvas.width;
    var canHeight=canvas.height;
    var pi=Math.PI;
    var timer=null;
    var ms=16;

    var gameBall={
        size:30,
        positionX:0,
        positionY:0,
        color:"#FFF",

        set setSize(newSize){
            this.size=newSize;
        },
        set setPosX(posX){
            this.positionX=posX;
        },
        set setPosY(posY){
            this.positionY=posY;
        },
        set setColor(newColor){
            this.color=newColor;
        },
        get getSize(){
            return this.size;
        },
        get getPosX(){
            return this.positionX;
        },
        get getPosY(){
            return this.positionY;
        },
        get getColor(){
            return this.color;
        }
    }

    function clearCanvas(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canWidth,canHeight);
    }

    function drawBackground(){
        ctx.fillStyle="#000";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canWidth,canHeight);
    }

    function drawBall(){
        ctx.save();
        var posX=gameBall.getPosX;
        var posY=gameBall.getPosY;
        var size=gameBall.getSize;
        ctx.fillStyle=gameBall.getColor;
        ctx.arc(posX,posY,size,0,2*pi,true);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function updateBall(){
        //clearCanvas();
        //drawBackground();
        gameBall.setPosX=gameBall.getPosX+3;
        gameBall.setPosY=gameBall.getPosY+3;
        drawBall();
    }

    gameBall.setPosX=100;
    gameBall.setPosY=100;
    drawBackground();

    timer=setInterval(updateBall, ms);
}
```

Comment: I would have suggested clearing the canvas on each update, before drawing new positions, etc. I see that you have that in your `updateBall` function, but it appears to be commented out. Am I right in saying that it didn't work?

Comment: The reason it is currently commented out is that I was trying a few different solutions (such as "ctx.save() and ctx.restore()"). Sadly neither works.

Comment: I created a fiddle (the code is slightly updated, but the issue remains)

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5HDu/288/

Comment: @Phrosen. I've added an answer showing a working version of your Fiddle after dealing with 2 issues. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

**Below is a working version of your Fiddle. It's refactored for these 2 issues:**

- Your prior balls are remaining because Canvas does not allow repositioning of existing ball drawings. The .save & .restore commands just save & restore the context properties -- they do not save & restore drawings on the canvas. Instead, you must erase the canvas and redraw the ball in its new position. So (1) drawBackground, (2) update & (3) drawBall in updateBall is a proper way of "moving" on canvas.
- You must call `context.beginPath` each time you draw your `context.arc` (ball). If not, all previous version of the .arc command will be redrawn.

```js
function eventWindowLoaded(){
 var canvas=document.querySelector("canvas");
 var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
 var canWidth=canvas.width;
 var canHeight=canvas.height;
 var pi=Math.PI;
 var timer=null;
 var ms=1000/60*1;

 var gameBall={
  size:30,
  positionX:0,
  positionY:0,
  color:"#FFF",

  set setSize(newSize){
   this.size=newSize;
  },
  set setPosX(posX){
   this.positionX=posX;
  },
  set setPosY(posY){
   this.positionY=posY;
  },
  set setColor(newColor){
   this.color=newColor;
  },
  get getSize(){
   return this.size;
  },
  get getPosX(){
   return this.positionX;
  },
  get getPosY(){
   return this.positionY;
  },
  get getColor(){
   return this.color;
  }
 }

 function clearCanvas(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canWidth,canHeight);
 }

 function drawBall(){
  ctx.save();
  var posX=gameBall.getPosX;
  var posY=gameBall.getPosY;
  var size=gameBall.getSize;
  ctx.fillStyle=gameBall.getColor;
    ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(posX,posY,size,0,2*pi,true);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();
 }

 function updateBall(){
  //clearCanvas();
  gameBall.setPosX=gameBall.getPosX+3;
  gameBall.setPosY=gameBall.getPosY+3;
    ctx.fillStyle='black';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  drawBall();
 }

 gameBall.setPosX=35;
 gameBall.setPosY=35;

 timer=setInterval(updateBall, ms);
}

eventWindowLoaded();
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #E93D19;
 color: #341711;
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-size: 2vw;
}

#content {
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 3%;
}

canvas {
 background-color: black;
}

nav {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 3vw;
}

#navlist {
 background-color: #FD851D;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0;
 transform: translateY(10%);
}

#navlist li {
 display: inline;
}

#navlist a {
 color: #C91D09;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#navlist a:hover {
 background-color: #C91D09;
 color: #FD851D;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <nav>
            <ul id="navlist">
                <li><a href="#">Button 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Button 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Button 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Button 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="content">
            <canvas width="600" height="400">Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas</canvas>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: But it's a lot of work for every update like we're performing a lot just to erase earlier version of the ball. I tried creating a ball with same as the background color but the color doesn't match the background. Is there a way to handle without re-building whole canvas again ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the canvas every time you redraw a frame.

When drawing paths, you need to make sure that you are creating a new path each frame, and not *adding on to the current path*. This is usually done by calling `ctx.beginPath()` to clear out the context's current path.

Comment: Do I need to close the path as well? I'm not quite sure what begin/closePath does, to be honest.

Comment: No, closePath simply creates a line between the last point and the beginning. It can be useful for making sure a path is "neat." Here's an example: http://codepen.io/simonsarris/pen/dMBRaQ?editors=1010

Comment: Actually, here's a better example of closePath: http://codepen.io/simonsarris/pen/QNXgoE?editors=0010